# Access Task (ToDo) object within Outlook web addin

Tags: outlook, task, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I can access Message (mail) and Appointment objects via the office-js library and show the add-in button within these objects to show the pane.

Is there any way how to show the pane in the Task object window?
[image]

In Appointment it is possible
[image]

Thank you for any hint. I suppose it is not just supported now and I will have to manage Tasks via Graph API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, add-ins are not supported on Task items, only appointments and mail messages. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Right now accepted answer as there is no possibility (except Graph API workaround) to do this from Office-js out-of-the-box.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/42943185-access-task-todo-object-within-outlook-web-addin

Comment: @Hourglasser How did you create a request on uservoice?  I get a message saying it's deactivated.  Also, it is being phased out.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/uservoice-pages-430e1a78-e016-472a-a10f-dc2a3df3450a

Comment: It is deactivated today - probably some shutdown, I do not know. Maybe @Outlook Add-ins Team-MSFT have answer? :)